# Errror using API in chrome browser

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I don't know how to fix this issue with using an API. It give me a browser error that says:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
> 'file:///C:/Users/Gebruiker/Desktop/PokeMax/GET%20https://api.pokemontcg.io/v2/cards?s'
> from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin
> requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome,
> chrome-extension, chrome-untrusted, https. jquery-3.4.1.min.js:2 GET
>
> file:///C:/Users/Gebruiker/Desktop/PokeMax/GET%20https://api.pokemontcg.io/v2/cards?s
> net::ERR_FAILED

If someone knows what the issue is I would love to hear it!

code:

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {

    $("#TheSubmitButton").on("click", function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
    
        var Pokemon = $("#search")
            .val()
            .trim()
        console.log(Pokemon);
    
    
    $.ajax({
    
      
        url: "GET https://api.pokemontcg.io/v2/cards?" + Pokemon,
        dataType: 'json',
        method: "GET"
    });
    
    
    });
    
    });
    
    // for (var i = 0; i < response.cards.length; i++) {
        //     var pokemonCard = $("<img>");
        //     pokemonCard.attr("src", response.cards[i].imageUrlHiRes);
        //     $("#card-container").append(pokemonCard);
        // }
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. You're hitting the [same origin policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy).  Unless you have control of api.pokemontcg.io (or influence over whoever runs it) you will not be able to make AJAX calls to it without [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing)

Comment: You cannot use `XMLHttpRequest` if you open your HTML with `file://` protocol. Use a server.